# How to make MS Query Parameters (?) OPTIONAL for usage (want to start with all data first AND THEN filter if needed)

Tags: mysql, excel, microsoft-query

I am pulling SQL data into Excel through Microsoft Query. I have set of 2 ? parameters for a set of sales data to filter by store # and by item, and I want them to be able to be used as alternative filter options, not necessarily both at the same time.

For example: Usually my users want to look at ALL the items's sales for ONE store, or ALL the stores for ONE item. So I want the 2 parameters to be set as optional to use, and unless filled in, the query to remain unfiltered.

Right now, my query data remains blank until I fill in the ? blanks to add data. Is it possible for me to set the default to be unfiltered first?

Currently I go to Excel --> "Data and Connections" --> "Properties" --> Definition tab --> Command Text: In this SQL query code, I add a WHERE clause for the parameters:

WHERE store_number = ?
AND
item_name = ?

Then of course I tell it which cell I want to plug the parameter into.
As a result, this starts me off with no data, until I fill BOTH parameters in. But I want it to start unfiltered for both, and then filter if I type in a parameter.

I have created a workaround with a macro button that goes to the query code and deletes one of the Where clause lines to eliminate the pre-filtering process, and another macro that "re-activates" the filter by adding the Where clause back in, but I wonder if there's a simpler way. Plus, this workaround is not as user-friendly with my end users who will be using the report.

Comment: When you say "Microsoft Query", **exactly** which Query tool are you referring to? (for example, _Microsoft PowerQuery_ is completely different from _Microsoft Query32_).

Comment: Not PowerQuery. Essentially I go to Excel --> Data tab --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Microsoft Query --> I select my SQL database from a picklist --> Prompt that asks if I would like to continue editing in Microsoft Query --> Yes. Here's where I build my table and export into Excel. Then I just made edits to my query in the "Data and Connection" area I mentioned above.